# How to create a shortcut in a c++ program (Keyboard input such as 'Alt' or 'Shift')

Tags: c++, windows, input, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to make a shortcut in my c++ program by using keyboard as a input.
For instance, if I use "Alt" + "A" + "D", I want to change my status (predefined in program) from user to administrator. 
How can I make this kind of shortcut (or keyboard input) to change some feature in the program?

(Window program)

Comment: [`RegisterHotKey` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Don't answer in comments. Comments are for clarifying the question. Post a real answer, that can be voted upon, commented upon, and accepted.

Comment: @DevSolar I usually do, but I didn't find it worthwile. The function was the first hit I got when entering "winapi keyboard shortcut" in google.

Comment: The second part: "_I want to change my status (predefined in program) from user to administrator._" should probably be removed from this question and put in a separate question (if it doesn't already have an answer - which I think it has). Search: [winapi: elevate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwinapi%5D+elevate)

Answer (score 2):

C is not the same as C++.

Compare the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) to the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

Standard C++11 does not know about keyboards. Check by reading the standard or by looking [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). For example, you can write a C++ compiler in standard C++11 (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [CLang](https://clang.llvm.org/)), and such a software does not know about keyboards. Keyboards are usually handled by [operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (and several [open source operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_operating_systems) are coded in C++).

And lots of C++ programs run on computers without any keyboards: from cheap [RaspBerryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/) devices to [TOP500 supercomputers](https://www.top500.org/).

If you code for Windows, you should learn and code for the [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program). Perhaps, as Ted Lyngmo commented, [using RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey).

If you code for a GUI, consider using a cross-platform GUI toolkit such as [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [FLTK](https://fltk.org/). Both are written in C++ and callable from C++ code. And both should work on Windows and on Linux: Your C++ code would be the same (at source level) for both Windows, Linux or MacOSX desktops.